# Can a wifi hot spot be set invisible to just one specific android device?

Tags: wi-fi, mac-address

The wifi hotspot i usually connect to has suddenly become invisible to just my android phone but is visible to everyone else. Is this possible or is there something wrong with my phone?

Comment: It's possible to block a certain device from connecting to a Wi-Fi hotspot. Just not sure if the hotspot would be hidden for the blocked phone though.

Comment: that is the dilemma!..its not visible to me but is visible to everyone else and all the other wifi hotspots are visible to me except the one in question.

Comment: Maybe it's configured for a channel your device does not support? In certain areas, there are limitations concerning which channels are permitted by law; so there could be a kind of "enforcement" in action on your device.

Comment: @Izzy that could be it but i have been using the same wifi hotspot for quite some time now and just yesterday it went out of range. and i can connect to the same wifi hotspot from other devices plus all the other wifi hotspots are still visible and connectable on my phone.

Comment: Then check on those who are able to join which channel they are using. And where the device is able to connect, check as well to see if there's an overlap (which would rule this out again).

Comment: @Izzy any idea how do i find out which channel the wifi hotspot is using?i have tried a few apps namely wifi analyser and a few more but none tell the channel on which the wifi signal is being broadcasted.

Comment: @Izzy just found out that my wifi doesn't display any wifi hotspot that uses 5GHZ frequency..guess my phone doesn't support 5ghz frequency

Comment: my phone supports the following protocols: Wi-Fi 802.11 b/g/n, 2.4 GHz, dual-band, Wi-Fi Hotspot. so does dual-band means it supports 5Ghz as well?

Comment: Not necessarily, it seems: [What Is a Dual Band Router?](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/wireless80211/f/dual-band-wireless.htm) explains it like "two antennas", so you could use e.g. 802.11g and 802.11n simultaneously (and not necessarily at different frequencies). I'd say that rather gets interesting with the device's hotspot features, serving different clients at the same time. // as for the channel: [Wifi Analyzer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Wifi-Analyzer/com.farproc.wifi.analyzer) and [WiEye](http://www.appbrain.com/app/WiEye-WiFi-Scanner/edu.smu.wispy) show it both.

Comment: thanks for all the help..the wifi hot-spot has been shifted from 2.4Ghz to 5Ghz frequency  which is not supported by my phone and hence the hotspot isn't visible anymore. guess its time to buy a new phone.